# VBA ignore and exclude blank rows with for loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have this code which I am trying to optimize. I wanted to exclude the row w/ blank cells but right now I do it separately thus it is running slow. Any insights will be highly appreciated.

```
Sub btn_CheckCDMSsummary()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Sheets("NF CDMS TO RDS").Cells().Clear
Dim RowRangeCDMSSum As Double
RowRangeCDMSSum = Sheets("CDMS ORDER SUMMARY").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("NF CDMS TO RDS").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Order No"

With Sheets("NF CDMS TO RDS").Range("A:A")
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    .Value = .Formula
End With

For i = 2 To RowRangeCDMSSum
    On Error Resume Next
        vlookval = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("CDMS ORDER SUMMARY").Cells(i, 2), Sheets("RDS ORDER SUMMARY").Range("A:A"), 1, False)
        matchval = WorksheetFunction.Match(vlookval, Sheets("RDS ORDER SUMMARY").Range("A:A"), 0)
        
        If vlookval <> Sheets("CDMS ORDER SUMMARY").Cells(i, 2) Then
            Sheets("NF CDMS TO RDS").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("CDMS ORDER SUMMARY").Cells(i, 2).Value
       End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i
MsgBox matchval
MsgBox vlookval

'delete empty rows in NF CDMS TO RDS
Dim RowRange2 As Double
RowRange2 = Sheets("NF CDMS TO RDS").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
For i = RowRange2 To 1 Step -1
    If IsEmpty(Sheets("NF CDMS TO RDS").Cells(i, 3)) Then
       Sheets("NF CDMS TO RDS").Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Sample:
My first FOR LOOP returns:
[image]

Want I expect as output
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using 'i' as your counter/tracker for both sheets, so the result is going to be that the two will look alike. Consider using a different tracker for the destination that only increments when the current row has been populated based on your code.

For example, even using 'j'

```
j = [first row to be used in your destination]
```

Then change the assigning code to:

```
Sheets("NF CDMS TO RDS").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("CDMS ORDER SUMMARY").Cells(i, 2).Value

j = j + 1
```

Then I believe you can remove the clean-up loop.

Hope this helps!

Here's what the new version of your code would look like:

```
With Sheets("NF CDMS TO RDS").Range("A:A")
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    .Value = .Formula
End With

j = [First Row]    'You'll need to identify how this is determined, although if you just want to start with the first row in then just use 1. 

For i = 2 To RowRangeCDMSSum
    On Error Resume Next
        vlookval = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("CDMS ORDER SUMMARY").Cells(i, 2), Sheets("RDS ORDER SUMMARY").Range("A:A"), 1, False)
        matchval = WorksheetFunction.Match(vlookval, Sheets("RDS ORDER SUMMARY").Range("A:A"), 0)
        
        If vlookval <> Sheets("CDMS ORDER SUMMARY").Cells(i, 2) Then
            Sheets("NF CDMS TO RDS").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("CDMS ORDER SUMMARY").Cells(i, 2).Value

        j = j + 1

       End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the suggestion, however, should this be in for loop also? i am sorry, i can't figure where and how i should insert it in my code.. :((

Comment: I wanted to know if I can just exclude the blank rows WHILE performing the first For Loop. Right now I am doing it AFTER my first For Loop..

Comment: The suggestion for setting the 'j' value would be just prior to your "For i = 2 To RowRangeCDMSSum" line. Then, within that loop, after the evaluation "If vlookval <> Sheets("CDMS ORDER SUMMARY").Cells(i, 2) Then", change that line to the line I provided above (all I did was change the 'j' from an 'i'). The next line after that is where you increment j (in my example above). Effectively, if the condition valuates as true, then it populates and moves to the next row (j). If the result is false, then the line doesn't execute and it won't advance to the next row until it evaluates as true again.

Comment: Oh my goodness, it worked and I understood your explanation! Really helpful! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do it in a `FOR` loop? You can do it in a single line using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`

```
Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Hi, this is ok but I wanted to know if I can just exclude the blank rows WHILE  performing the first For Loop. Right now I am doing it AFTER my first For Loop

Comment: Also I tried to use Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete instead of my For loop but it ended as blank sheet :(( all values are deleted

Comment: Did you change to `Columns("C:C")` since the original column that you're looking at is column C?

Comment: You're reading `Sheets("CDMS ORDER SUMMARY").Cells(i, 2)` in the `FOR` loop 3 times per loop, perhaps you should assign it to something. As for ignoring and skipping the blank rows, just add a if statement that checks if the cell is blank before proceeding with the `VLOOKUP`. Also what's the purpose of `matchval` apart from just showing in the msgbox? Is it Necessary in the loop? Can you do it outside the loop?